# FileProvider Problem in Android Version 9

Tags: android

I recently got a crash report in Fabric about fileproviders. In Android version<9 fileproviders seems to work fine but in version 9 particularly `ONEPLUS A6010`. Crash report says

`Caused by java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/999/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Images/IMG-20190328-WA0072.jpg`

I have seen storage path to sdcard like `/storage/emulated/0/...` .
So I started to google about storage path `/storage/emulated/999` found that this path is related to `Parallel App Storage`.

My `fileprovider.xml` is

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path
        name="/storage/emulated/0"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

I am not getting any clue about how to deal with parallel app storage (about the crash). I searched in Stackoverflow and found solutions to only sdcard path i.e `/storage/emulated/0` but not for storage path `/storage/emulated/999`. Has anybody faced this crash before?

complete crash log

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/999/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Images/IMG-20190328-WA0072.jpg
   at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:712)
   at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:401)
```

Comment: Where/how are you getting a file path of `/storage/emulated/999/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Images/IMG-20190328-WA0072.jpg` in your app, such that you are trying to serve it via `FileProvider`.

Comment: @CommonsWare am using `multiphotochooser` where am listing all the images available in mobile device using  `MediaStore` i.e `final String[] columns = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID};
        final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN;` and am adding the image path to arraylist from cursor iteration like `int dataColumnIndex = imageCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            imageUrls.add(imageCursor.getString(dataColumnIndex));` finally serving the arraylist to adapter with radio button in adapter item.

Comment: Please don't tag questions with IDE tags (android-studio) just because you use that IDE: these tags should only be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags), and the [tagging guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging).

Answer (score 0):

`FileProvider` cannot serve files that your app cannot access, and `FileProvider` cannot serve files from removable storage.

Moreover, if these are already indexed in the `MediaStore`, you do not need `FileProvider` in the first place. Use a `Uri` pointing to the content in `MediaStore`:

- Get the `_ID` column value from the `MediaStore`
- Use `ContentUris.withAppendedId()` to attach that `_ID` to the root `Uri` that you used to query `MediaStore`

For example, in [this Java class](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/FINAL/Java8/VideoLambda/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/recyclerview/videolist/Video.java), given a `Cursor` pointing at a `MediaStore` row, I assemble a `Video` object that, among other things, holds a `Uri` pointing at the `Video`. The [overall sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/FINAL/Java8/VideoLambda) displays the videos in a `RecyclerView`.

Comment: AFAIK fileproviders are serving removable storage images i.e of sdcard. I have path of image `String filepath=/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20190401_145102.jpg` then using this line of code doesnt crash `Uri uriForFile = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MultiPhotoChooser.this, IMAGE_FILE_PROVIDER, new File(filepath));`

Comment: @MohammedFarhan: "AFAIK fileproviders are serving removable storage images i.e of sdcard" -- no, sorry. "then using this line of code doesnt crash" -- that is external storage, not removable storage.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code in `file_paths.xml`:

```
<root-path
      name="root-path"
      path="" />
```

Then you can access removable storage and clone app storage.